# Previously active cell

Tags: excel, vba, events

For the code I am writing I monitor the changes in certain cell ranges to run functions and private subs. For this I use the Intersect function in the `worksheet_change` sub.

However, the trigger for the intersect 'test' is always that I 'move out' of the cell I am testing for whether it'd be via mouseclick into a different cell or via cursor move.

What I need is a way to define a variable which contains the `.address` of the cell I had selected before.

I tried the code below, but all I get is errors.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

```
Public xfrLastCell As String
Public xfrActiveCell As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If xfrActiveCell = "" Then xfrActiveCell = ActiveCell.Address
xfrLastCell = xfrActiveCell
xfrActiveCell = ActiveCell
MsgBox xfrLastCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

below code works for me - your assignment of activecell was missing an Address meaning activecell variable is always blank

```
Option Explicit

Public xfrLastCell As String
Public xfrActiveCell As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If xfrActiveCell = "" Then xfrActiveCell = ActiveCell.Address
xfrLastCell = xfrActiveCell
xfrActiveCell = ActiveCell.Address
MsgBox xfrLastCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

With this code, referring `PreviousActiveCell` will return desired result:

```
Public PreviousActiveCell as Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static pPrevious as Range
    Set PreviousActiveCell = pPrevious
    Set pPrevious = ActiveCell
End Sub
```

This works inside single worksheet. Do you need a previous cell across other sheets and workbooks?

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to "remember" the Range rather than the address of the range:

```
Dim Oldcell As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Oldcell Is Nothing Then
        Set Oldcell = Target
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MsgBox "New cell is " & Target.Address & vbCrLf & "Old cell was " & Oldcell.Address
    Set Oldcell = Target
End Sub
```

Comment: -1 This is non-working example! `OldCell` will always point `ActiveCell`!

Comment: Hi LS_dev:  Your point is 100% correct!  It is only **within** the sub that Oldcell is important.  It determines where you came from.

Answer (score 0):

`If` is unnecessary. I have used this:

```
Public sPreviousTarget As String
Public sTarget As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  sPreviousTarget = sTarget
  sTarget = Target.Address
End Sub
```

Also, `Target` is different from `ActiveCell` (`ActiveCell` refers to one of the cells in `Target`).