# Last active cell row

Tags: vba, excel, row

I'm having difficulties with the "ActiveCell.Row" command on a VBA code, I know it must be a simple fix, but I've done some research and didn't find an answer to my problem.

The code bellow is getting the row number of the next active cell, and not the cell that I've edited.

Example: If I edit the cell "B2" and press enter, it returns the row of B3, because that will be the current active cell when the code runs. If I press tab, it returns the right number which is "2" because the active cell will be "C2". And if I press the up-arrow it returns the row "1", because the active cell will be "B1".

I appreciate your help! Thanks!
(P.S. I've tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179756/previously-active-cell) and some others I've found, but without success)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Alvo As Range)
    Dim limite_maximo As Integer
    limite_maximo = 1000
    If Alvo.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Alvo) Then Exit Sub

    If Alvo.Column = 2 And Alvo.Row >= 1 And Alvo.Row <= limite_maximo Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        a = ActiveCell.Row - 5
        b = 10
        Alvo.Offset(0, 2).Value = b
        Alvo.Offset(0, 3).Value = a
        Alvo.Offset(0, 4).Value = b & "." & Format(a, "000000")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Alvo` is the cell(s) that was/were changed so you should use that and not `activecell`

Comment: `Alvo` is the range of the cell you have changed. So use `Alvo.Row` to get the row.

Comment: Awesome dude!
I've changed the line

a = ActiveCell.Row - 5
to
a = Alvo.Row - 5

And now it works perfectly!
Sorry for the newbie question, but I was really struggling with that one.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Excel *Options,* the cursor moves down after entering data in a cell. 
  If I install:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox Target.Row
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```

and edit cell **B9,** the first output will be **9** but the second output will be **10.**

This way you can determine the row number of the cell that was changed and the row number of the active cell after the change occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Got it thanks to the comments of [Paul Kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4474195/paul-kelly) and [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611989/rory)

I've changed the line "a = ActiveCell.Row - 5" to "a = Alvo.Row - 5" and now it works perfectly! Sorry for the newbie question, but I was really struggling with that one.

Thanks!