# Remember cell selected before double click

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet that has a **doubleclick** event in cell "P1" (runs a macro).

I may have cell "J30" (or any other cell) selected before I **doubleclick** "P1"
How can I remember, and return to the cell "J30" after the "P1" **doubleclick**?

Storing the active cell doesn't work because the first click in the doubleclick sequence, selects "P1".

I also tried rightclick on "P1", but it also selects "P1" before running the event.

Comment: Not a duplicate there. I can store the active cell before a cell change event, but I need to store it before a "double click" event.

Comment: I'm trying to cancel the flag, but don't seem able to..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a bit more complicated than the "duplicate thread" because the `SelectionChange` event is invoked prior to the `BeforeDoubleClick` event, so the former will update the last selection to the new one before the latter gets hand.

What you need is to go "one step further" in saving the selections, by actually saving both:

- The current selection
- The previous selection

Something like this should work

```
' Code module of your worksheet
Option Explicit
Private lastSelection As Range, beforeLastSelection As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  ' Your Code for this event, i.e.
  If Target.Address = "$P$1" Then
    ' Some code ...
     Cancel = True
     If Not beforeLastSelection Is Nothing Then beforeLastSelection.Select
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Set beforeLastSelection = lastSelection
  Set lastSelection = Target
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

[Using the method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179756/previously-active-cell) you can do as follows

```
Public PreviousActiveCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox ("Previous selection: " & PreviousActiveCell.Value & vbNewLine & _
    "Double clicked selection: " & Target.Value)


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Static pPrevious As Range
    Set PreviousActiveCell = pPrevious
    Set pPrevious = ActiveCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Almost similar answers. +1 for hiding `pPrevious`, I like and usually apply the good practice of hiding variables as much as possible. However I'd prefer `Set pPrevious = Target`.I also  showed more detail as to how to process the `BeforeDoubleClick`. :)

Comment: +1 back at you, your answer is more helpful to the OP directly as I was relying on the link to explain the rest!