# Check on ActiveCell before Target.Address

Tags: excel, vba

I want an if clause to be true if the ActiveCell was "A1" before I clicked on "A2".
Its not connected with a button or anything. It has to work by just clicking on "A2".
That's my try i made:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A2" And ActiveCell.Cells(0, 0) = "A1" Then
MsgBox ("test")
End If
End Sub
```

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: you can't have Cells(0, 0) as this doesn't exist

Comment: see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179756/previously-active-cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Previously active cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179756/previously-active-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong approach here.

If you use the `SelectionChange` event then it means the selected cell already changed. You have to stock the address of the last cell every time the event is called. To do the trick, put your condition before stocking the `ActiveCell` as the lastCellAddress and it works perfectly.

Here is the code with comments to help you understand:

```
'Declare the variable out of the event
Dim lastCellAddress As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Check if the last selected cell was A1 when selecting A2
    If (ActiveCell.Address = "$A$2" And lastCellAddress = "$A$1") Then
        'If the condition is true display your MsgBox
        MsgBox ("test")
    End If

    'Set the current address as the last selected for next selection change
    lastCellAddress = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @crat Glad it helped :)