# Excel VBA Run Macro when Cell is deselected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table tbl1 with a list of names. When I select any row in the column "name", I would like to run a macro to filter another table tbl2. When I deselect that same row, I would like to run another macro to unfilter tbl2.

So far, I have gotten the filter on select part working, but I am stuck on how to get it to unfilter on deselect. FilterTableByName and UnfilterTableByName are both macros that will filter/unfilter tbl2.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 
 If Not Intersect(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl1").ListColumns("name").Range, Target) Is Nothing Then
    Call FilterTableByName(ActiveCell.Row)
 End If
 
 End Sub
```

An alternate solution that I thought of was to call unfilter and then filter macros on select, and then call unfilter when I leave the worksheet, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to unfilter instead of running it every time I click a different worksheet. Thanks

Comment: Unless I am misreading your question, wouldn't you just need an `Else` in your `If`, if it doesn't meet your intersect criteria then unfilter it?

If you do need to know the previously selected cell, Krishnas answer in here should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179756/previously-active-cell

Comment: Adding an else will cause it to unfilter if I select anywhere else on the worksheet outside the "name" column. I only want it to unfilter if I select a column immediately after I select a cell in the "name" column. I think storing the previously selected cell is helpful, but I am not sure how to use it cleanly. Maybe do If (select any column outside "name" AND last selected cell == value)? I'll see if I can put it together